How to add each item in a list to the end of each dictionary item in a list of dictionarys
I have two arrays, like below:
user_data = [{'a': '1', 'b': '3'}, {'a': '2', 'b': '4'}, {'a': '5', 'b': '1'}]
available_times_array = ['12:00', '12:10', '12:20']

And I'm waiting to have this result array:
user_data = [
    {'a': '1', 'b': '3', 'c': '12:00'},
    {'a': '2', 'b': '4', 'c': '12:10'},
    {'a': '5', 'b': '1', 'c': '12:20'}]


So what's your actual question, and what have you tried already?

Please post your attempt and show your code

What have you tried? This is really basic stuff. For example, do you know how to loop over a list? Do you know how to add an item to a dict? Stack Overflow isn't really built to teach the basics, so if you haven't done a Python tutorial, do that first. If this is homework, please read How to ask and answer homework questions. See also [ask].

(also note that Python does not have arrays, it has lists, so resist the urge to call things arrays, even in variable names)

BTW, when you say "array", you mean list. Arrays are different, like NumPy arrays or array.array.

Possible duplicate (assuming you know how to do the stuff I mentioned before): How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?

user_data = [{'a': '1', 'b': '3'}, {'a': '2', 'b': '4'}, {'a': '5', 'b': '1'}]
available_times_array = ['12:00', '12:10', '12:20']

for data, time in zip(user_data, available_times_array):
    data['c'] = time

print(user_data)


this is not the idiomatic way to do this, and should be avoided. In python, you practically never want for i in range(len(whatever)):, you just want for x in whatever:, in this case, you want to use zip, something like for d, t in zip(user_data, available_time_arrays): ...

I trust that this answer is now more idiomatic.

Yep! See how much more readable that is?

you can try to add a new item to each dictionary using a for loop like this.
for i in range(len(user_data)):
    user_data[i]['c'] = available_times_array[i]


this is not the idiomatic way to do this, and should be avoided. In python, you practically never want for i in range(len(whatever)):, you just want for x in whatever:, in this case, you want to use zip, something like for d, t in zip(user_data, available_time_arrays): ...
